# Python regular expression using the OR operator

Tags: python, regex, or-operator

I am trying to parse a large sample of text files with regular expressions (RE). I am trying to extract from these files the part of the text which contains *'vu'* and ends with a newline *'\n'*.

Patterns differ from one file to another, so I tried to look for combinations of RE in my files using the *OR* operator. However, I did not find a way to automate my code so that the *re.findall()* function looks for a combination of RE.

Here is an example of how I tried to tackle this issue, but apparently I still can not evaluate both my regular expressions and the OR operator in *re.findall()*:

```
import re

def series2string(myserie) :
    myserie2 = ' or '.join(serie for serie in myserie)
    return myserie2

def expression(pattern, mystring) : 
    x = re.findall(pattern, mystring)
    if len(x)>0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

#text example
text = "\n\n    (troisième chambre)\n    i - vu la requête, enregistrée le 28 février 1997 sous le n° 97nc00465, présentée pour m. z... farinez, demeurant ... à dommartin-aux-bois (vosges), par me y..., avocat ;\n"

#expressions to look out
pattern1 = '^\s*vu.*\n'
pattern2 = '^\s*\(\w*\s*\w*\)\s*.*?vu.*\n'

pattern = [pattern1, pattern2]
pattern = series2string(pattern)

expression(pattern, text)
```

*Note* : I circumvented this problem by looking for each pattern in a *for loop* but my code would run  faster if I could just use *re.findall()* once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python regular expressions uses the `|` operator for alternation.

```
def series2string(myserie) :
    myserie2 = '|'.join(serie for serie in myserie)
    myserie2 = '(' + myserie2 + ')'
    return myserie2
```

More information: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

---

The individual patterns look really messy, so I don't know what is a mistake, and what is intentional. I am guessing you are looking for the word "vu" in a few different contexts.

1. Always use Python raw strings for regular expressions, prefixed with `r` (`r'pattern here'`). It allows you to use `\` in a pattern without python trying to interpret it as a string escape. It is passed directly to the regex engine. [(ref)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)
2. Use `\s` to match white-space (spaces and line-breaks).
3. Since you already have several alternative patterns, don't make `(` and `)` optional. It can result in catastrophic backtracking, which can make matching large strings really slow.
   `\(?` → `\(`
   `\)?` → `\)`
4. `{1}` doesn't do anything. It just repeats the previous sub-pattern once, which is the same as not specifying anything.
5. `\br` is invalid. It is interpreted as `\b` (ASCII bell-character) + the letter `r`.
6. You have a quote character (`'`) at the beginning of your text-string. Either you intend `^` to match the start of any line, or the `'` is a copy/paste error.
7. Some errors when combining the patterns:

   ```
   pattern = [pattern1, pattern2, pattern3, pattern4]
   pattern = series2string(pattern)

   expression(re.compile(pattern), text)
   ```

Comment: Could you update your question to include the corrected code? Keep the original code there for context, otherwise this answer won't make good sense.

Comment: What is it that you want to match? How did you get your patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your tips. My regular expressions were a little clumsy in my first post (I changed them hoping the question would be more understandable). I managed to capture the *OR* operator '`|`' thanks to '`re.compile`' and the code works fine!

```
import re

def series2string(myserie) :
    myserie2 = '|'.join(serie for serie in myserie)
    return myserie2

def expression(pattern, mystring) : 
    x = re.findall(pattern, mystring)
    if len(x)>0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

#text example
text = "\n\n    (troisième chambre)\n    i - vu la requête, enregistrée le 28 février 1997 sous le n° 97nc00465, présentée pour m. z... farinez, demeurant ... à dommartin-aux-bois (vosges), par me y..., avocat ;\n"

#expressions to look out
pattern1 = r'^\s*vu.*\n'
pattern2 = r'^\s*\(\w*\s*\w*\)\s*.*?vu.*\n'

pattern = [pattern1, pattern2]
pattern = series2string(pattern)

expression(re.compile(pattern), text)
```