# understanding raw string for regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex, newline, rawstring

I have lots of text files full of newlines which I am parsing in python 3.4. I am looking for the newlines because they separate my text into different parts. Here is an example of a text :

```
text = 'avocat  ;\n\n       m. x'
```

I naïvely started looking for newlines with '`\n`' in my regular expression (RE) without thinking that the backslash '`\`' was an escape character. Howerver, this turned out to work fine:

```
>>> import re

>>> pattern1 = '\n\n'
>>> re.findall(pattern1, text)
['\n\n']
```

Then, I understood I should be using a double backslash in order to look for one backlash. This also worked fine:

```
>>> pattern2 = '\\n\\n'
>>> re.findall(pattern2, text)
['\n\n']
```

But on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690450/python-regular-expression-using-the-or-operator), I was told to use raw strings instead of regular strings, but this format fails to find the newlines I am looking for:

```
>>> pattern3 = r'\\n\\n'
>>> pattern3
'\\\\n\\\\n'
>>> re.findall(pattern3, text)
[]
```

Could you please help me out here ? I am getting a little confused of what king of RE I should be using in order to correctly match the newlines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't double the backslash when using raw string:

```
>>> pattern3 = r'\n\n'
>>> pattern3
'\\n\\n'
>>> re.findall(pattern3, text)
['\n\n']
```

Answer (score 2):

OK I got it. In this nice [Python regex cheat sheet](https://github.com/tartley/python-regex-cheatsheet/blob/master/cheatsheet.rst) it says:
"*Special character escapes are much like those already escaped in Python string literals. Hence regex* '`\n`' *is same as regex* '`\\n`'".

This is why `pattern1` and `pattern2` were matching my text in my previous example. However, `pattern3` is looking for '`\\n`' in already interpreted text, which actually is '`\\\\n`' in canonical string representation.